# Installing compass or FFI not working

Tags: angularjs, ruby, macos, compass

I've tried installing compass and ffi on osx but get the same error.
I've reconfigured and reinstalled ruby, I've installed Xcode command line tools, I've rebooted my machine, nothing seems to fix the exact same error every single time. I'm about to wipe my machine and start anew, I have no idea why I can't get past this error when trying gem install compass:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160508-18749-v694wb.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

```
Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-ffi_c-dir
        --without-ffi_c-dir
        --with-ffi_c-include
        --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
        --with-ffi_c-lib
        --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/
        --with-libffi-config
        --without-libffi-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `block in try_compile'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:502:in `with_werror'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `try_compile'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1038:in `block in have_header'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:889:in `block in checking_for'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:888:in `checking_for'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1037:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

`/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-15/2.0.0/ffi-1.9.10/mkmf.log`

extconf failed, exit code 1

Comment: `brew install libffi` try this

Comment: Tried that as well, getting this:

"Warning: libffi-3.0.13 already installed"

Still no progress. I can install other gems though without issue.